# Spring Boot application not including the Thymeleaf templates

Tags: spring, eclipse, maven, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have packaged a spring boot service using Maven "mvn clean package". this is my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.noentenimnicinc.iot.web</groupId>
  <artifactId>nicinc-web</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring Boot dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>uk.co.jemos.podam</groupId>
            <artifactId>podam</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.5.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- nicinc-core dependencies -->
        <dependency>
             <groupId>com.noentenimnicinc.iot.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>nicinc-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Webjars for JQuery and Bootstrap -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.7-1</version>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>3.0.2.RELEASE</version> -->
        </dependency>


   </dependencies>

 <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

and everything works fine running the class from Eclipse -> Run As -> Java Appplication, but running the application from the command line, I realize that all the files included in src/main/resources are not included in the jar, so I have this error accessing the application:

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Wed May 10 10:54:16 CEST 2017
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Error resolving template "/nicinc/login/login", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

here the structure of the module project:

[image]

Comment: You have to keep static files under src/main/resources/templates source directory.

Comment: indeed, is where they are

Comment: Have to create source folder called 'templates'. Please provide src/main/resources/templates in Folder Name text box.

Comment: I am also using Thymleaf with `parent` `<version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>` in the `pom.xml`. See if it works for you.

Comment: in which artifact ?

Comment: In your `pom.xml` there is a `<parent>` tag. Try changing its version.

Comment: I have the same result, anyway Its always better to work with the last version